# macOS recovery mode not recognizing WiFi

Tags: macos, network, recovery

I'm trying to reinstall macOS Sierra. I'm working in a room with a WiFi extender.

When I boot up in recovery mode I get the network selection dropdown.

Selecting the right network and typing in the right password just put me back on the netwerk selection dropdown.

I didn't have a network cable to connect directly to my router.

Answer (score 2):

The fix was: move closer to my (wireless) router and bypass the extender.

Not sure why this worked, but it did.